# What is the user agent string of Samsung Galaxy S4 mini in native browser

Tags: user-agent

What is the user agent string of Samsung Galaxy S4 mini in native browser?

Comment: IF you're on the device you can go to this site http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Model Variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4#Model_variants) section of the Galaxy S4 wikipedia article, you can find the SGH-* codes to search for. Also, there is a link to an [article about the S4 mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4_Mini). There you can find model numbers, such as this one (the only one at the time of writing) GT-I9195. Simply [search the web for "GT-I9195 user agent"](https://www.google.com/search?q=GT-I9195+user-agent+string) and you will probably find what you're looking for, for example:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; en-us; SAMSUNG GT-I9195 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 Chrome/18.0.1025.308 Mobile Safari/535.19

Of course, if you actually have access to a device/browser for which you'd like to know the user-agent string you can simply examine the [HTTP request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) with a tool like [WebInspector](http://dannguyen.github.io/NICAR/2012/02/25/nicar-2012-inspect-the-web-with-your-browsers-web-inspector/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). As other users have pointed out, there are also convenient tools online to do this for you such as, [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/) and [user-agent-string.info](http://user-agent-string.info/parse).